# Batch file to read the last line from .tmp even if it starts with ; character

Tags: batch-file

Hell everyone, I have a weird question to you.

*I have this .tmp file.*

```
M l FNT;yriad_b
M l FNT;arial_bo
mm
zO
J
O R,P
H50,5,T
D -3.0,2.2

F98;arial_bo
F99;yriad_b
Sl1;0.0,0.0,100,100,100
P -1.8

T:Line01;6.5,6.5,0,98,pt23;XXX
G 0,8.5,0;L:70.5,0.7
T:Line04;5.5,14.2,0,99,pt18,q100;XXXX
T:Line05;5.5,18.2,0,99,pt9,q100;XXXX
T:Line88;5.5,26.0,0,99,pt21,q100;XXXX
T:Line08;5.5,68.0,0,99,pt21,q100;XXXX
B 5.5,70,9,code128, 7,.4;XXXX
T:Line99;5.5,61.8,0,99,pt11,q100;XXXX
B 5.5,85,5,code128, 7,.25;XXXX
T:Line09;5.5,82.8,0,99,pt17,q100;XXXX
T:Line10;5.5,33.3,0,99,pt17,q100;XXXX
B 5.5,35,2,code128, 7,.3;XXXX
T:Line11;5.5,48.1,0,99,pt18,q100;XX
T:Line19;16.0,48.1,0,99,pt18,q100;XX

B 5.5,50.0,0,code128, 7.0,.3;8


A 1







;ABC123
```

and I need to get the last line, exactly **ABC123** without **;** character.
I am currently using the batch script below, which works if I do not have the **;** character before ABC123. I do not know why the batch script skips the lines stars with **;** character.

*Batch script.*

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (c:\print\pack2.tmp) do set Build=%%x
```

**Can anybody help me ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is skipped due to the `eol` option of [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loops which defaults to the `;` character.

Unlike the `delims` option, you cannot simply disable the `eol` option by stating the option string `"eol="`, because this would set it to the `"` character. A string like `"eol= delims="` would also not work because this would take the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> as the `eol` character.

To disable the `eol` option there are several possibilities:

1. Hiding it behind the `delims` option:

   ```
   for /F "usebackq eol=, delims=," %%L in ("file.txt") do set "Build=%%L"
   ```

   Specifying an `eol` character to one of the given `delims` characters disables `eol` as `delims` seems to have the higher priority to `for /F`. The order of `eol` and `delims` does not matter.
2. Using the odd unquoted syntax:

   ```
   for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("file.txt") do set "Build=%%L"
   ```

   Every token separator (<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`, `=` and also the non-break space `0xFF`) must be escaped by preceding `^`. Here, `eol` must be specified as the last option. The unescaped <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is not taken as the `eol` character, because it is consumed by the parser to separate the option string from the `for` variable reference `%%L`.
3. Using the odd line-break syntax:

   ```
   for /F usebackq^ eol^=^

   delims^= %%L in ("file.txt") do set "Build=%%L"
   ```

   The empty line is mandatory here. The `^` after the `eol^=` part constitutes line continuation, so the first line break (CR+LF, carriage-return line-feed sequence) is ignored. The next character, an LF (the CR is already skipped by the parser when reading the line of code), is taken literally as the `eol` character. Since such cannot occur within lines of text as they mark the end of line, the `eol` option is finally disabled.

Answer (score 3):

It skips lines beginning with `;` as this is the default EOL character, see also `FOR /?`.

To avoid this you could change the EOL to another character like

```
for /f "EOL=Y delims=" %%x in (c:\print\pack2.tmp) do set Build=%%x
```

If you know that a specific character can't be at this position, then you can choose it.

Or you use enclose the file with findstr, so that each line starts with a line number (then the `FOR/F` can grab also empty line).

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" c:\print\pack2.tmp') do (
   set "line=%%L"
   set "Build=!line:*:=!"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes my problem solved. I did not know about EOL option.

Answer (score 0):

REM

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40888302.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*eol=;delims=; " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
SET var=%%~a
)
ECHO "%var%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q40888302.txt` containing your data for my testing.